# scanf и printf в С++

Tags: c++, c, header

Могу ли я использовать scanf и  printf в С++?

Comment: **Да**. Можете.

Comment: Вопрос в некотором смысле звучит как анекдот "Доктор, смогу ли я после операции играть на скрипке?"

Comment: Да уж, обхохочешься ;)

Answer (score 4):

Согласно стандарту C++ ( C++ 17, 20.2 The C standard library)

> 1 The C++ standard library also makes available the facilities of the
>   C standard library, suitably adjusted to ensure static type safety.

и (20.5.1.2 Headers)

> 3 The facilities of the C standard library are provided in the
>   additional headers shown in Table 17

в которой (то есть в таблице) указан также заголовок `<cstdio>`, который содержит, в частности,  функции `scanf` и `printf`.

И далее

> 4 Except as noted in Clause 20 through Clause 33 and Annex D, the
>   contents of each header cname is the same as that of the corresponding
>   header name.h as specified in the C standard library (Clause 2). In
>   the C++ standard library, however, the declarations (except for names
>   which are defined as macros in C) are within namespace scope (6.3.6)
>   of the namespace std. **It is unspecified whether these names
>   (including any overloads added in Clause 21 through Clause 33 and
>   Annex D) are first declared within the global namespace scope and are
>   then injected into namespace std by explicit using-declarations
>   (10.3.3).**

Последнее означает, что не обязательно C-функции помещены в глобальное пространство имен. Из этого следует, что если вы не используете using-директиву в своей программе

```
using namespace std;
```

то программа с обращением к этим функциям будет структурно выглядеть следующим образом:

```
#include <cstdio>
// ...
int main()
{
    // ...
    std::printf( "Hello %s\n", "Zars.Stars" );
    // ...
}
```

То есть в общем случае вам следует включать именно заголовок `<cstdio>` и использовать квалифицированные имена вроде `std::printf`.

Answer (score 2):

Да. Вот пример:

```
/* scanf printf example */
#include <stdio.h>

int main () {
  char str [80];
  printf ("Enter your name: ");
  scanf ("%79s",str);  
  printf ("Hello, %s.\n",str);  
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Но наверное лучше использовать `<cstdio>`.